# Сортировка массива по заданному критерию

Tags: c#

Допустим есть  класс А

```
class A:IComparable
{
    int pole1;
    int pole2;
    public int CompareTo(A other)
    { 
        return this.pole1.CompareTo(other.pole1);
    }
}
```

И есть класс Б

```
class B<T>
{
    T[] arr;
    public void Sort()
    {
        Array.Sort(arr);
    } 
}
```

Класс Б содержит массив объектов класса А.
Вопрос в чем, когда я буду вызывать из мейна сортировку объекта класса Б, все они будут сортироваться по полю `pole1`. Логично, потому что я так указал.
Как сделать так, что бы сортировка шла по выбору пользователя, т.е. сортировать по полю `pole1` или по полю `pole2`.
 Я так пологаю, нужно как-то указывать признак, но не понимаю как это реализовать. Подскажите как правильно реализовать метод `CompareTo()` и `Sort()`

Comment: реализуйте 2 компаратора и передайте нужный. Или что-то хитрее надо?

Comment: Как Array.Sort(arr); будет понимать какой компаратор использовать?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 вот например.

Comment: Читал я уже мсдн, я там не разобрался, так бы тут не задавал вопрос.

Comment: 2 параметром пробовали передавать в функцию sort компаратор, наследник IComparer  ? Как в примере.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример?

Comment: + когда реализовал второй компаратор в классе А, компилятор ругается, что определен член с таким же именем(compare to)  и с тем же набором параметров

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков, а как ты хочешь задавать по какому полю сортировать? Обязательно ли использовать Array.Sort? может подойдет [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Я же и спрашиваю - как. Да, обязательно использовать Array.Sort.
Может как-то можно в Array.Sort(arr)  дополнительно  к массиву передать тот самый признак, по которому я хочу отсортировать ? Хотя бы строку?

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков, поля класса `A` приватные? или их можно поменять на публичные? если они только приватные, тогда единственный вариант передавать их извне - строка, но тогда не совсем понятно в чем смысле приватности, если пусть и опосредованно о них знают извне?

Comment: Хорошо, допустим они паблик, как тогда сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У функции [`Array.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) есть перегрузка принимающая делегат [`Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Таким образом можно объявить разные функции сравнения непосредственно внутри класса, например

```
class A
{
    int pole1;
    int pole2;

    public static int CompareByP1(A a, A b)
    {
        return a.pole1.CompareTo(b.pole1);
    }
    public static int CompareByP2(A a, A b)
    {
        return a.pole2.CompareTo(b.pole2);
    }
}
```

И использовать их в качестве параметра

```
Array.Sort(b.arr, A.CompareByP2);
Array.Sort(b.arr, A.CompareByP1);
```

Для использования из класса B, нужно добавить параметр `Comparison<T>`, который будет передаваться в метод sort

```
public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)
{
    Array.Sort(arr, comparison);
}
```

И использоваться, как

```
b.Sort(A.CompareByP2);
```

Comment: Можно как-то сделать тут так, что бы признак передавался без указания класса А ? Т.к. класс Б может хранить в себе не только массив классов А, но и другие классы, как я в вопросе и указал это поле шаблонное.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков, Обновил ответ

Comment: Вот так что надо ! Большое спасибо;)

Answer (score 1):

Почитал MSDN сделал так и работает.

```
class ComparePole2 : IComparer<A> // объявляем класс который реализует IComparer
{
public int Compare(A x, A y) //Сравниваем по pole2.
 {
    return x.pole2.CompareTo(y.pole2);
 }    
}
class A : IComparable<A>
{
  public  int pole1;
  public  int pole2;
  public int CompareTo(A obj)
 {
    return pole1.CompareTo(obj.pole1);
 }    
}
class B<A>
{
  public A[] arr;
}
Array.Sort(b.arr); // Сортируем по pole1.
Array.Sort(b.arr,new ComparePole2); // Сортируем по pole2.
```

Comment: Что-то совсем не то. Если у меня будет 10 полей, так что и классов тогда 10 штук реализовывать? Плюс поля класса А и Б у меня инкапсулированы, к ним не должно быть доступа из-вне. Спасибо за совет, но это не подходит.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков вопрос был как сортировать по pole1 или pole2 и как реализовать CompareTo() и Sort().Я на них ответил. На счет 10 полей не знаю,если бы они были открыты можно было бы просто использовать Linq. Вы всегда можете сделать подкласс ComparePole2  где вам нужно.

Comment: Просто по мне это как-то не практично, создавать для каждого сортируемого поля свой класс, наверняка есть поизящнее решения.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков Linq - b.arr.OrderBy(x => x.poleX); Очень изящно.

Comment: К сожалению про Linq первый раз слышу и в  своей задаче мне нужно обойтись без этой функции.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков: Вам ехать или шашечки? Изящное однострочное решение или без LINQ?

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое LINQ и в своей задаче не могу это применить.